# hibernate.cfg.xml cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist. Spring MVC Hibernate web app error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdYQOqxq9F0

Building Eclipse Maven project for Web App, using Spring-MVC and Hibernate with MySQL. Using Apache Tomcat 8 as server.

After many hours trying to solve this, I am stuck.

Please help, thank you. I am getting this error.

Error: [EDITED]

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bgolubovic.service.StudentService com.bgolubovic.controller.StudentController.studentService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bgolubovic.dao.StudentDao com.bgolubovic.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl.studentDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.bgolubovic.dao.impl.StudentDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">



<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bgolubovic" />    


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>com.bgolubovic.model.Student</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>CRUDWebAppMavenized1</groupId>
<artifactId>CRUDWebAppMavenized1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties> 
 <org.springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>       
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
 </dependency>

<!-- Hibernate resources -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Alpha1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>20030825.184428</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    <version>20030825.183949</version>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>CRUDWebAppMavenized</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=******
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>        
    <mapping class="com.bgolubovic.model.Student" />
</session-factory>         
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your *spring-orm-*.jar is corrupted or is incompatible with existing spring jars or you have multiple conflicting versions of same jar. Check for these and correct the dependencies to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` from Hibernate 4 but have (mostly) Hibernate 3 dependencies installed.  Updating your versions to 4 should solve this - just go through your pom.xml and change them all.

e.g.

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>`

etc

Comment: I change it to:

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
 </dependency>

But still the same error.

Comment: @bgolubovic  make sure you've updated all of the older dependencies and force a Maven update if necessary to pull in all the newer jars.

Comment: I change spring dependency to 4.0.x version, and now get this error:

Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)

Comment: As you can see in question, I already have hibernate.cfg.xml
And it is in WEB-INF directory

Comment: I know. :( It is in src\main\webapp\WEB-INF. Thank you for your comments and your time.

Comment: No worries - I hope you fix it.  One last thing: try a copy (if there isn't already) of the file in src/main/resources - hibernate.cfg.xml likes to live there.

Comment: Check your build path - sounds like it could be missing elements of your classpath.

Comment: [build path pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/co8g12p8ewjqr08/builth.jpg?dl=0) I think everything looks good here?

Comment: The web-inf directory is not in the class path. You should move the file to WEB-INF/classes or chance the URL removing classparh: in the spring configuration and replace to WEB-INF/ to search the file in the context root of the application

Comment: @FernandoRincon I did that, hibernate.cfg.xml is already in target/WEB-INF/classes. No solution. Remove classpath: and put WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml, again no solution. How I need to put for as you said to WEB-INF/ to search the file in the context root of the application? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems JAR version issue.

You are trying to use `hibernate 4` in your `spring-servlet.xml`.

While in your pom you refer `version 3`.

Comment: When I change Hibernate 4 ->3 in pom.xml I get this:
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'annotatedClasses' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'annotatedClasses' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: why don't you use hibernate 4 in your pom too,instead of 3?

Comment: I change that also, and try 4 everywhere. I needed to change Spring also to 4.0.x version. I get now this error:

Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)